# Differentiating to find $I_n (a)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $I_n (a)$= $\int_0^1 x^a (\ln(x))^n  \,dx$ for $a > 0$ and $n=0,1,2,...$

Find $I_0 (a)$. Differentiate in $a$ to find $I_n (a)$ for all $n \ge 1$

The first part, I'm assuming I can sub in $n=0$ so I have to integrate $x^a$ which is clear, and then sub in the values.

But for the second part, I have little idea. From a google search, there is something to do with differentiating under the integral, but I have no idea how to do this or how to apply it. Any advice appreciated!

Comment: Just apply integration by parts differentiating $(\ln{(x)})^n$ and integrating $x^a$. What do you get?

Comment: For $a<1$ we have a problem... $a=1/2$  and n=2 the derivative  $\frac{-1}{2}x^{-1/2}(\log{x})^2$ is not integrable..the integral of the derivative diverges..are you sure that $a>0$ and not $a \geq 1$??

Comment: Well, you already know how to solve it, just differentiate under the integral sign with respect to a. See also here:: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3372053/515527

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we perform one round of integration by parts we can start to see a pattern:

$$
I_n(a)= \int_0^1 x^a\ln^n(x)dx=\left . \frac{1}{a+1}x^{a+1}\ln^n(x)\right|_0^1  -\frac{1}{a+1}\int_0^1 n x^a\ln^{n-1}(x)dx =-\frac{n}{a+1}I_{n-1}(a).
$$

From here we can prove by induction that

$$
I_n(a)  =  (-1)^n\frac{n!}{(a+1)^{n+1}}.
$$

The base case for $n=0$ is simple since $\int_0^1x^adx=\frac{1}{a+1}$.  Assuming it’s true for $I_n(a)$ then we can use the computation in the above line to show that

$$
I_{n+1}(a)= -\frac{n+1}{(a+1)}I_n(a)=(-1)^{n+1}\frac{(n+1)!}{(a+1)^{n+2}}.
$$

Comment: Thanks. My only query is how you get to the line after "From here we can prove by induction that"...?

Comment: Try looking up proof by induction.  The way these statements are proved are of the form “show that the statement works for $n=0$, then show that if it’s true for $n$ then it also must be true for $n+1$.”  The way I solved it was by inferring a pattern from the first relation, and then using induction to show that it is in fact true for all $n$.

Comment: I know about induction and how to use it, I'm just unsure why you've let $$I_n(a)  =  (-1)^n\frac{n!}{(a+1)^{n+1}}.$$

Comment: I didn’t “let” $I_n(a)$ equal anything.  I *made a claim* as to its value, and then proved that claim true using induction.

Comment: Ok, I get that but that value comes out of the blue for me. Where has it come from?

Comment: It comes from deriving the recursion relation between $I_n(a)$ and $I_{n-1}(a)$.  There is a multiplicative factor of $-\frac{n}{a+1}$ at the $n$th level.  If we can figure out $I_0(a)$, which is pretty easy to find, we can the figure out $I_1(a)=-\frac{1}{a+1}I_0(a)=-\frac{1}{(a+1)^2}$, and all other values of $I_n(a)$ in this fashion.  Jumping to the expression I gave is really based on this, but positing that value without offering a proof isn’t proper.  Induction is the correct way to justify this.  At least it’s quicker than integrating by parts the whole way.